# Need to identify plant

Tags: houseplants

Can someone help identify this plant? Thanks!
See below picture.
[image: Leaves look like lemon balm, but this plant has no smell to its leaves]

Answer (score 1):

Pilea nummulariifolia (Sw.) Wedd.

OR -CREEPING CHARLIE

Comment: Welcome! While it’s perfectly fine to answer your own question, you could significantly improve the answer by adding more details, e.g. what are the characteristics that help future readers to identify this plant? In other words, think also about the *why* beyond the *what*. Additional information like water / light / fertilizer / … preferences can be a nice touch as well. If you want, [answer] should help write better answers.

Comment: "Creeping charlie". while a common name used for this plant, is commonly associated with quite a different plant, which is a pernicious lawn weed. A more common "common name" for this plant is Swedish Ivy.  I am glad that you used the botanical name, which prevented me from writing an entirely different comment.